# TortoiseGit: How to configure remote url (local directory folder)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Basically users test my apps in `/test`, while I wait for their approvals I build more of the app in `/test2`. I have been manually copying all files in `/test2` to `test` using beyond compare. There has to be a better way. Which is why I would like to either push from `/test2` repo to `test` repo or pull from `/test2` repo into `test1` repo.

I can't seem to get the correct Remote URL format.

For the Remote URL, I've tried :
`\\test` ,`\\test\.git` , `file:///x://test/`, `file:///x://test/.git`, `x:/test`

Currently running TortiseGit on Windows Xp, also tried on Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the slash at the end, and it should work fine!